# Upper left corner Mozilla darkened on extended display, Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, firefox, extended-desktop, classic-shell

I have this:  Dell XPS 13, running Windows 8.1 & Classic Shell, with an extended display to an HP 22 uh monitor.

Mozilla Firefox Quantum 63.0.3 (64-bit) gets a darkened rectangle in the upper left corner when greater than a certain size.  The issue is not location on the screen.  I've included images of the effect, and my screen resolution dialogue. Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Of course, I can work around this.

[image: This is the effect.]
[image: No shading when sized smaller.]
[image: No shading when moved to upper left.]
[image: My screen resolution dialogue.]

Comment: Apologies--I don't know why my image descriptions don't show up.

Comment: Ooops, too many 60-range numbers.  Yes, I'm running 63.0.3.  I'll try to edit the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes this problem is caused by a non-standard theme.
If you have installed or created a theme, try to use standard theme in order
to check.

Otherwise, try to restart Firefox in Safe mode.
If this solves the problem, then the problem is caused by an add-on:

- Click the menu button
- Click Help
- Select *Restart with Add-ons Disabled…*.

If the problem still exists in Safe mode, resetting Firefox might help.
First
[backup your profile](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/back-and-restore-information-firefox-profiles)
and
[export bookmarks](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer),
then
[Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings):

> The refresh feature fixes many issues by restoring Firefox to its
>   default state while saving your essential information like bookmarks,
>   passwords, and open tabs.
>
> Important: Since Firefox will revert to its original state, your own
>   configurations and customizations, including extensions, extension
>   data, and about:config preference configurations are removed. If
>   you've made accessibility configurations, you may need to change them
>   back after refreshing.

Comment: Bingo.  Selecting "Restart with Add-ons Disabled" seemed to work.  I had to re-launch Firefox manually, but the effect was gone.  BUT, when I go to the add-on page three of the four seemed to be enabled, and it looks like they are active now.  I'm a little perplexed by that.

Comment: Ooops...meant to add this: I'm using the XP Default theme.  Should I change that for any reason?

Comment: I think it was the XP Default theme that had gone rogue.  Once I restarted in safe mode, I could enable it without a problem.  After that, the problem has remained fixed. Sorta makes sense, because the problem was with the display.  Thanks.